# Websocket (spring) ssl connection (empty chain)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ssl, spring-websocket

Good day! I have a simple chat application with websocket (STOMP).
I have configured ssl connection with mutal auth.

Server side:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=path/to/server.jks
server.ssl.trust-store=path/to/trusted.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=22222222
server.ssl.trust-store-password=22222222
server.ssl.client-auth=need
```

client :

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","path/to/client.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","22222222");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","path/to/trusted.jks");  
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","22222222");
```

server trusted.jks and client trusted.jks are the same.

so when I try to connect with

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

I get lots of output and some strange situation - I can see two(?) key-agreements. The first one goes ok -

```
  trustStore is: /path/to/trusted.jks

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=ca@ca.com, CN=ca, OU=ca, O=ca, L=ca, ST=ca, C=RU
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=ca@ca.com, CN=ca, OU=ca, O=ca, L=ca, ST=ca, C=RU
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x9952f188496b2545
  Valid from Wed Jun 28 15:39:04 MSK 2017 until Sat Jun 26 15:39:04 MSK 2027
```

So my CA cert is added as trusted. Then

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
//ok
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
//ok
*** Certificate chain
//my localhost server cert
***
Found trusted certificate:

 Version: V3
 Subject: EMAILADDRESS=ca@ca.com, CN=ca, OU=ca, O=ca, L=ca, ST=ca, C=RU
 Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
```

So my client found trusted certificate for this server certificate.

```
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
//ok
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Cert Authorities:
```

```
*** ServerHelloDone
```

And I can find my CHAIN -

```
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=client3@mail.ru, CN=client3, OU=client3, O=client3, L=client3, ST=client3, C=RU
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=ca@ca.com, CN=ca, OU=ca, O=ca, L=ca, ST=ca, C=RU
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
*** CertificateVerify
*** Finished
```

As far as I know - this is ok. 
Then I can see:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "https://localhost:8443/chat/info" resulted in 200 (null)
DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport - Starting WebSocket session on wss://localhost:8443/chat/437/f6158d1ee84b4c53ba55a6810b2f92a8/websocket
DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient - 
Connecting to wss://localhost:8443/chat/437/f6158d1ee84b4c53ba55a6810b2f92a8/websocket
```

Again adding trust store certificate and so on, all is the same, but

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=ca@ca.com, CN=ca, OU=ca, O=ca, L=ca, ST=ca, C=RU>
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

So the server says to me

```
ttps-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9, fatal error: 42: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
```

Any thoughts about problem? If it is needed I can post my keystores and client implementation here.
Thank you for help!

UPDATE with curl output

```
 env -i curl -E ./chain.pem --key ./client.key --cacert ca.crt --verbose --user test:test  https://localhost:8443/

*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* found 1 certificates in ca.crt
* found 704 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs 
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: localhost (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: 

C=RU,ST=localhost, 
L=localhost,O=localhost,OU=localhost, 
CN=localhost,EMAIL=localhost@mail.com
*    start date: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 13:07:14 GMT
*    expire date: Thu, 28 Jun 2018 13:07:14 GMT
*    issuer: C=RU,ST=ca,L=ca,O=ca,OU=ca,CN=ca,EMAIL=ca@ca.com
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server auth using Basic with user 'kitcpp'
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8443
> Authorization: Basic a2l0Y3BwOmtpdGNwcA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=67BACDE78AF68627516075B29C987C86; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 16:29:53 GMT
 < Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Language: en-US
< Content-Length: 6935
< Date: Fri, 30 Jun 2017 09:30:02 GMT
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
//and so on (my web chat page)
```

Comment: Have you tried taking WebSockets out of the picture and seeing if you can establish an HTTPS connection with mutual auth?

Comment: Andy Wilkinson, if I may say so - I installed my user certificates to chrome and connected to the chat via web client.

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers my question or not. What does "web client" mean? To keep things simple, I'd use something like `curl` to verify that mutual auth works with HTTPS. That will either show that the problem is pretty fundamental, or that it's something specific to WebSockets.

Comment: Andy Wilkinson, I have updated my answer with curl output

Comment: Ok, so the basic SSL configuration is fine. Looking at your code: firstly, there's quite a lot of it. A _minimal_ sample would make it a lot easier for people to help you. Secondly, your SSL configuration on the client-side looks a bit suspect to me. You have set various system properties, but you've done so after initialising the `SSLContext`. Furthermore, you've initialised it with no key and trust managers. I'm not sure that will work.

Comment: Andy Wilkinson, by the way - Spring rest api worket great with same settings and same keystores. Anything else you need me to provide with code and keystores?

Comment: Andy Wilkinson, here is a small client-server proof. just incert path to keystores (they are inside the certs dir) https://github.com/RedCollarPanda/spring_websocker_bug_test

Comment: Andy Wilkinson,  any news?

Comment: Your SSL configuration still looks wrong to me. Have you read [Tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/web-socket-howto.html#Tomcat_Web)?

Comment: Andy Wilkinson, yes, Im using embeddet tomcat with propper configurtion. If you say that is looks wrong to you - I guess you can tell where it is wrong? What do you mean? As I said in one of comments - Spring Rest API works great with THE SAME configuration. I assume this is a bug in Spring websocket. So may be I should reopen (or open another) bug in Spring git repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Tomcat's WebSocket client. [Its documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/web-socket-howto.html#Tomcat_Web) describes how it should be configured to use SSL:

> When using the WebSocket client to connect to secure server endpoints, the client SSL configuration is controlled by the userProperties of the provided `javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig`. The following user properties are supported:
>
> - `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT`
> - `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_PROTOCOLS`
> - `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_TRUSTSTORE`
> - `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PWD`
>
> …
>
> If the `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT` property is set then the `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_TRUSTSTORE` and `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PWD` properties will be ignored.

You're using Spring's WebSocket and it is creating the `ClientEndpointConfig` for you. To configure its user properties you set them on the `StandardWebSocketClient` and it will then use them when it creates the `ClientEndpointConfig`. For example, assuming that the default SSL context is sufficient:

```
StandardWebSocketClient simpleWebSocketClient =
        new StandardWebSocketClient();
Map<String, Object> userProperties = new HashMap<>();
userProperties.put("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT", SSLContext.getDefault());
simpleWebSocketClient.setUserProperties(userProperties);
```

Comment: @Furetto, this question and answer are about Tomcat. If you're interested in how to do something similar with Jetty, please ask a new question with more context so that potential answerers can see exactly what you're trying to do.